# Kubernetes events - how to get continuous stream of events?

Tags: java, kubernetes, events

I was reading about Kubernetes events and it seems the only way to process events is to create a Watch over http call, which in turn processes the response and becomes Iterator of events. But that is finite and you have to recreate the event watch constantly... Is there a way to simply tail events with some callback, in Java?

Answer (score 2):

As a native watching method for Kubernetes, you can watch events in real-time with `--watch`  [flag](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) - it is a part of API server, allowing to fetch the current state of resource/object and then subscribe to subsequent changes:

```
kubectl get events --watch
```

There is no in-built solution in Kubernetes for storing/forward event objects on the long term as by default the events have a 1-hour life span. You would need to use third-party tools to stream the events continuously, e.g. -  [Kubernetes Event Exporter](https://github.com/caicloud/event_exporter?ref=thechiefio); to collect them and export to external systems for alerting/further processing - e.g. [kubewatch](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch?ref=thechiefio), [kubernetes-event-exporter](https://github.com/opsgenie/kubernetes-event-exporter) tools.